# Where to mock to test a Django view that calls a service?

Tags: python, django, python-mock

This is Django 1.6.8, Python 2.7, and the [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/1.0.1) library.

I have a view that calls a remote service using suds for sales tax information (this is a simplified version):

```python
def sales_tax(self, bundle_slug):
    bundle = get_object_or_404(Bundle, slug=bundle_slug,
                                active=True)

    cloud = TaxCloud(TAXCLOUD_API_ID, TAXCLOUD_API_KEY)
    origin = Address('origin address')
    destination = Address('customer address')
    cart_item = CartItem(bundle.sku, TAXCLOUD_TIC_ONLINE_GAMES,
                        bundle.price, 1)

    try:
        rate_info = cloud.get_rate(origin, destination,
                                    [cart_item],
                                    str(customer.id))

        sales_tax = Decimal(rate_info['sales_tax'])

        response = {'salesTax': locale.currency(sales_tax),
                    'total':  locale.currency(bundle.price + sales_tax)}
    except TaxCloudException as tce:
        response = {
            'error': str(tce)
        }
```

Here's relevant code from the `TaxCloud` class:

```python
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault

class TaxCloud(object):

    def __init__(self, api_login_id, api_key):
        self.api_login_id = api_login_id
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.soap_url = 'https://api.taxcloud.net/1.0/TaxCloud.asmx'
        self.wsdl_url = 'https://api.taxcloud.net/1.0/?wsdl' 

        self.client = Client(url=self.wsdl_url, location=self.soap_url, faults=False)

    def get_rate(self, billing_address, origin_address, raw_cart_items, customer_id):
        address = self.convert_to_address(billing_address)
        origin = self.convert_to_address(origin_address)
        cart_items = self.convert_to_cart_list(raw_cart_items)

        response = self.client.service.Lookup(self.api_login_id,
                                              self.api_key, customer_id,
                                              self.cart_id(customer_id), cart_items,
                                              address, origin, True, None)

        if( response[1].ResponseType == 'Error' ):
            raise TaxCloudException(response[1].Messages[0][0].Message)

        return {
            'sales_tax': str(response[1].CartItemsResponse[0][0].TaxAmount),
            'cart_id': response[1].CartID
        }
```

In my test for the view, I don't want to call the remote service. Using [this example of a mocked client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284506/374383), I built out a dumb mock class (my `ClientMock` matches exactly the example in that answer):

```python
class TaxCloudServiceClientMock(ClientMock):
    """
    Mock object that implements remote side services.
    """

    def Lookup(cls, api_id, api, customer_id, cart_id, cart_items,
               address, origin, flag, setting):
        """
        Stub for remote service.
        """
        return """(200, (LookupRsp){
               ResponseType = "OK"
               Messages = ""
               CartID = "82cabf35faf66d8b197c7040a9f7382b3f61573fc043d73717"
               CartItemsResponse =
                  (ArrayOfCartItemResponse){
                     CartItemResponse[] =
                        (CartItemResponse){
                           CartItemIndex = 1
                           TaxAmount = 0.10875
                        },
                  }
                })"""
```

In my test, I'm trying to `@patch` the `Client` used in the `TaxCloud` class:

```python
@patch('sales.TaxCloud.Client', new=TaxCloudServiceClientMock)
def test_can_retrieve_sales_tax(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    tax_url = reverse('sales_tax', kwargs={'bundle_slug': self.bundle.slug})
    self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='testpassword')

    response = self.client.get(tax_url, {'address1': '1234 Blah St',
                                        'city': 'Some City',
                                        'state': 'OH',
                                        'zipcode': '12345',
                                        'country': 'US'},
        HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The remote call is still being made, however. Based on the "[Where to mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch)" documentation, I'm correctly targeting `sales.TaxCloud.Client` instead of `suds.client.Client`.

What could be causing the patch to be ignored/bypassed?

Comment: I'm not a Django expert, but my guess is that `TaxCloud` object is not build at request time but a django service init time. You should try to `patch` `sales.TaxCloud.Client.service.Lookup`  instead and use `return_value` instead of your own new mock.

Comment: @melissa did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @cph2117 Unfortunately not. We've been able to mock other service calls just fine using the method I describe above, but not this.